# How to insert id from url to my create method

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

i'm trying to create a product which belongs only to one order. That order id i'm taking with me to create form, but don't know how to pull it to store function.
Updated files:
ProductController:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Order;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Order $order){
       
        return view('order.product-create', compact($order));
    }

    public function store(Order $order, Request $request){

   $this->validate($request, [
    'name'=>'required',
    'drawing'=>'nullable|file',
    '3d_file'=>'nullable|file',
    'quantity'=>'integer',
    'unit_price'=>'required',
    'discount'=>'nullable'
   ]);
   $order->products()->create($request->all());
   session()->flash('product-created', 'New product was added successfully');    
   return redirect()->route('order.view');
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/order/{order}/product/create', 'ProductController@create')->name('product.create');
Route::post('/order/{order}/product', 'ProductController@store')->name('product.store');
```

view.blade.php ---> link to product create form

```
<a href="{{route('product.create', $order)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Add new product</a>
```

product.create.blade.php ---> fragment to method action

```
action="{{route('product.store', ['order' => $order])}}"
```

so with this at the moment, i can't get in to product-create.blade.php with error $order is undefined

Comment: ok, did that, so now when trying to get in order/product/create getting $order is undefined

Comment: Just updated my answer, you do need to pass the order parameter on create sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic parameters are defined as curly braces in your route file in routes/web.php or routes/api.php

```
// routes/web.php
Route::get('/order/{order}/product/create', 'ProductController@create')->name('product.create');
Route::post('/order/{order}/product', 'ProductController@store')->name('product.store');
```

Use Route model binding in ProductController.php to have Laravel resolve the order out of the container.

```
// ProductController.php
use App\Order;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Order $order)
    {
        // Only get here if laravel resolves the $order model

        return view('order.product-create', compact('order'));
    }

    public function store(Order $order, Request $request)
    {
        // Only get here if laravel resolves the $order model

        //validation
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'       => 'required',
            'drawing'    => 'nullable|file',
            '3d_file'    => 'nullable|file',
            'quantity'   => 'integer',
            'unit_price' => 'required',
            'discount'   => 'nullable'
        ]);

        // Create related Product model and associate it with the Order model.
        // https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method
        //
        // Need to allow for mass assignment in the Product.php model
        // https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment
        $order->products()->create($request->all());

        // Flash to session and redirect after creating
        session()->flash('product-created', 'New product was added successfully');
        return redirect()->route('order.view');
    }
}
```

view.blade.php

```
<a href="{{route('product.create', ['order' => $order]))}}" class="btn btn-primary">Add new product</a>
```

product.create.blade.php

```
action="{{route('product.store', ['order' => $order])}}"
```

Comment: hmm getting this error now Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameters for [Route: product.store] [URI: order/{order}/product/create]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bakalauras\resources\views\Order\product-create.blade.php)

Comment: @Ramse what is your form action parameter or ajax that is sending the post request?

Comment: action="{{route('product.store')}}"

Comment: you need to pass the `order` parameter in your route. Change your action to `action="{{route('product.store', ['order' => $order])}}"` or whatever your order variable is in your view. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes

Comment: after changes became more messy so i updated question with all related files. Hope it's more clear now. Thanks for being patient for newbies :)

Comment: also updated public function create($order){
       
        return view('order.product-create', ['order' => $order]);  so now able to get in to the form, but when submiting getting Route [order.view] not defined

Comment: hmm updated like you said, but still getting Undefined variable: order (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bakalauras\resources\views\Order\product-create.blade.php)

Comment: to get this working I had to change compact($order) to compact('order',$order). Not sure why but it solved the undefined variable issue. Thanks for help

Comment: You are correct, it should've been the string name of the variable like `compact('order')`, glad you have it working now.

Answer (score 1):

The way i understood, you want to pass the `Order ID` from your create form to your controller function, and based on that you want to save your form data.

You can pass your Order ID to your `POST route` by

`{{ route('route_name', ['order_id' => $order->id]) }}`

and your Route in `web.php` would be

`Route::post('/order/{order_id}/product/create', 'ProductController@store')->name('route_name)`

[Create Method with Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)
[Relationship Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

You can accept your parameters passed with in your controller function by

```php
public function store($order_id)
{
   //validation

   //save function
   $order = App\Order::findOrFail($order_id);  //Fails if the passed id is not present in DB
   // Assuming you have one to one relationship
   // Product() is the relationship you declare in your model
   $product = $order->Product()->create([
       'your_columns' => 'values',
   ]);

   // redirect after save

}
```

Edit : Updated Question

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Order;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Order $order){

       // you are receiving the Order instance by the Order ID (primary key defined) 

        return view('order.product-create', compact($order));
    }

    public function store(Order $order, Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [
           'name'=>'required',
           'drawing'=>'nullable|file',
           '3d_file'=>'nullable|file',
           'quantity'=>'integer',
           'unit_price'=>'required',
           'discount'=>'nullable'
        ]);

         $order->products()->create($request->all());
         session()->flash('product-created', 'New product was added successfully');    
         return redirect()->route('order.view');
    }
}
```

and your `Routes`

```php
// order = order id which is passed to the controller Order $order variable instance

Route::get('/order/{order}/product/create', 'ProductController@create')->name('product.create');
Route::post('/order/{order}/product/create', 'ProductController@store')->name('product.store');
```

Your form `POST`

```php
// You can pass the ID of the order result you receive from your `create` function

<form action = "{{ route('product.store',['order' => $order->id]) }}" ... >
```

Comment: That error i'm getting.. Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::store(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\bakalauras\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 1 expected

Comment: Can you show me your `post` route in web.php ? @Ramse

Comment: it was Route::post('/product', 'ProductController@store')->name('product.store'); but i changed to Route::post('/order/{order}/product', 'ProductController@store')->name('product.store'); and now getting 404

Comment: Are you passing `order` variable to create function now ?

Comment: i think so yes, just updated to my current code so this might be more clear where i am

Comment: `{{dd($order)}}` in create.blade.php file and if you are getting the order related info, then you have successfully passed, seeing your `create function` and the `create route` don't match up, create function in controller accepting an $order variable, but you haven't got a variable for the order id in your GET route

Comment: oh yes, forgot to update create function and create route. So should be like this Route::get('/order/{order}/product/create', 'ProductController@create')->name('product.create'); but still doesn't make sense why i'm getting Undefined variable: order (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bakalauras\resources\views\Order\product-create.blade.php)

Comment: yea.. all exactly same in my side, but still same.. error.. $order is undefined

Comment: Can you check with `dd($order)` inside your create function ?

Comment: App\Order {#997 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "orders"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:8 [▶]
  #original: array:8 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}

Comment: to get this working I had to change compact($order) to compact('order',$order). Not sure why but it solved the undefined variable issue. Thanks for help

Comment: Great that it worked out, or if you are trying to pass a simple variable use `with()` method